# Pine Script - "Internal server study error" - TradingView

Tags: pine-script

everyone! I'm facing with the error *"Internal server study error"* when setting `strategy(close_entries_rule= "ANY")` and try to close a position with `strategy.close(id= "EL 2")`.

The following code taken from *kodify.net* seems working to the article author, but when I copy and save in my TradingView Pine editor it give me *"Internal server study error"*

```
strategy(title="Exit from specific entries", overlay=true,
     pyramiding=2, close_entries_rule="ANY")

// Determine trading conditions
newDay = (dayofmonth != dayofmonth[1])

firstEntry  = newDay and (dayofweek == dayofweek.monday)
secondEntry = newDay and (dayofweek == dayofweek.tuesday)

firstExit  = newDay and (dayofweek == dayofweek.thursday)
secondExit = newDay and (dayofweek == dayofweek.friday)

// Submit entry orders
if (firstEntry)
    strategy.entry(id="EL 1", long=true)

if (secondEntry)
    strategy.entry(id="EL 2", long=true)

// Generate exit orders
if (firstExit)
    strategy.close(id="EL 2")

if (secondExit)
    strategy.close(id="EL 1")
```

Thanks you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It must be because you are running the strat on US markets, which don't allow hedging. Should work on non-USD forex or cryptos. See this from the [refman on `strategy()`](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#fun_strategy):

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nope, I've tried also with non-US forex, but it doesn't work...

Comment: It works on crypto (see chart added in answer). We'll see what TV means by "non-US forex" and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Change the source (Stock market) to your own market.

[image: Screenshot of market sources showing various countries and the European Union.]

change the source(Stock market) to your own market